# Middle button for scroll with tracking point and for paste on Thinkpad Trakpoint keyboard II

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad, scrolling, paste

I have a laptop Thinkpad E14 and an external keyboard ThinkPad TrackPoint Keyboard II (with radio, but tried also with BT), with Ubuntu 20.10 (but the issue was also in 20.04 LTS).

The issue is that trying to scroll from external keyboard, using tracking point and middle button, first trigger the paste and after the scroll. The same combination on laptop keyboard is working as should (also worked on an 1st version of the Thinkpad Trackpoint USB version and BT version)

I used `xev` to see how the middle button behaves on the laptop (and older keyboard) and the new one and observed that is a time delay between the `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease`.

For example this is what I get from the laptop (and also on old kb):

```
  ButtonPress event, serial 88, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
      root 0x7c1, subw 0x0, time 12475973, (554,631), root:(3415,1172),
      state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES

  ButtonRelease event, serial 88, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
      root 0x7c1, subw 0x0, time 12475973, (554,631), root:(3415,1172),
      state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
```

and this is what i get on the ThinkPad TrackPoint Keyboard II

```
  ButtonPress event, serial 88, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
      root 0x7c1, subw 0x0, time 12413819, (555,28), root:(3416,569),
      state 0x0, button 2, same_screen YES

  ButtonRelease event, serial 88, synthetic NO, window 0x3600001,
      root 0x7c1, subw 0x0, time 12413899, (555,28), root:(3416,569),
      state 0x200, button 2, same_screen YES
```

My guess is this time delay is causing this bad behavior.

I found a temporary solution on web, by disabling the paste on that middle button with:

```
  alias mc-off='xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"'
  alias mc-on='xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"'
```

Any advice to make it work as should, like on the laptop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this article some weeks ago https://www.phoronix.com/news/ThinkPad-TrackPoint-II-Linux, and give me hope. I can say today that kernel 5.19.1 **SOLVED** the middle button scroll.